# CefSharp load Lan address

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp 57 to load a local network address that my website is published to.  The address is associated with my domain and anyone not on this domain would have to vpn in to see the webpage.  I can see the website just fine with chrome as well as load any webpage with cefsharp (eg youtube.com).  I am using `browser = new ChromiumBrowser("http://10.199.1.71:8077")`.  I can right click on the cefsharp page to view source and it will popup with a text file that has the html that my website uses but cefhsarp shows a blank page.  Any advice or can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks